Task :react-native-apk:verifyReleaseResources FAILED aapt2 W 12-17 01:21:47 56908 1841875 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'
$ ./gradlew build
> Task :react-native-apk:verifyReleaseResources FAILED
aapt2 W 12-17 01:21:47 56908 1841875 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-apk:verifyReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > 1 exception was raised by workers:
     com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
     /Users/anhduc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4cb43db8d3aba6ac6adca96092eed276/transformed/appcompat-1.0.2/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:5:5-8:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
         
     /Users/anhduc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/4cb43db8d3aba6ac6adca96092eed276/transformed/appcompat-1.0.2/res/values-v28/values-v28.xml:9:5-12:13: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
         
     /Users/anhduc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/907f4ed0536cfc3cacbc5a53fef9773d/transformed/core-1.0.1/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
         
     /Users/anhduc/.gradle/caches/transforms-3/907f4ed0536cfc3cacbc5a53fef9773d/transformed/core-1.0.1/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
         


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.9/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

package.json
"dependencies": {
...
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",
"react-native-apk": "^0.2.7",
...
}
android build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        appCompatVersion = "1.4.2"
        googlePlayServicesLocationVersion = "20.0.0"  // Or higher.

    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath ('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1')

        classpath ('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3')
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

app build.gradle
android {
    ndkVersion '21.1.6352462'
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
...
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.63.2"  // From node_modules

    addUnimodulesDependencies()

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0"

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:19.0.1'

    ...

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.3.0'

    // For animated GIF support
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.14.2'

    ...

    // For WebP support, including animated WebP
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-webp:1.14.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:webpsupport:1.14.2'
    implementation project(':react-native-view-pdf')
}

gradle-wrapper.properties
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-bin.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

This error occurs when I run ./gradlew build, with the JDK version I'm using being zulu-11. I want to fix the current errors to upgrade the Gradle version.
